# IEnumerable перенести записи

Tags: c#

есть функция которая возвращает записи из базы `IEnumerable<Persons>`

```
Persons
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

есть второй Model, Client

```
Clients
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

и есть третья Model, Customers

```
Customers
{
   public IEnumerable<Client> Data {get; set;}
}
```

моя задача перенести записи `IEnumerable<Persons>` в Customers(data)

Comment: Самое банальное: `foreach(var person in Persons) Customers.Data.Add(new Client(person.FirstName));`, более красивее: `Customers.Data = Persons.Select(x=>new Client(x.FirstName));`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А почему не в ответы?

Comment: @AK Потому, что я не вижу смысла вообще в этом вопросе и будь моя воля, я бы его закрыл/удалил. Он неясен, выше лишь догадки, ну и не имеет ценности для базы SO, ибо как по мне, любой в силах пройтись циклом по массиву. Так что, пусть отвечают те, кому нужна репутация, а я постою в сторонке и понаблюдаю.

Comment: Так же, для простых кейсов маппинга можно воспользоваться библиотекой automapper, подробности по ссылке - https://automapper.org/

Comment: А зачем вам отдельный класс `Client`? Чем вас `Person` не устраивает? Или вы что-то нкдоговариваете. Покажите оригинальный компилируемый код. Тот что вы показали, не компилируется.